# My contact form using ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The code is this. It's not responding. JavaScript.
Am trying to do a contact form.

```
function sendContact() {
var valid;
valid = validateContact();
if(valid) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "contact.php",
        data:'name='+$("#name").val()+'&email='+$("#email").val()+'&subject='+$("#subject").val()+'&content='+$(content).val(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
            $("#mail-status").html(data);
        },
        error:function (){}
    });
}
}
```

The php file is

```php
<?php
include_once "config.php";

$name = validate($_POST["name"]);
$email = validate($_POST["email"]);
$message = validate($_POST["message"]);
$subject = validate($_POST["subject"]);
$to = 'myemail@example.com';


 $mailHeaders = "From: " . $name . "<" . $email . ">\r\n";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $mailHeaders)) {
 print "<p class='success'>Contact Mail Sent.</p>";
} else {
print "<p class='Error'>Problem in Sending Mail.</p>";
 }

 function validate($data)
 {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not responding"? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: I changed the email to protect the original poster from spam. However, the post should still be improved with explanations about what is happening that should not be happening. A generic description of "it's not responding" is not enough information to understand what the problem might be. Feel free to give details about the error, error codes, screenshots, etc.

Comment: jQuery's `$.ajax()` `data` property is **much easier** to set as an object instead of a string. You get proper encoding too

Comment: It is not giving any response. No error

Comment: Probably should include the HTML for the form, that would help. Also, jQuery .serialize would help a bunch with creating the post data. $("#formid").serialize() instead of concatenating that long string. https://api.jquery.com/serialize/